# VDC booster effect on LiFePo battery run time?

Tags: lifepo4, step-up

Looking for info to devise a solution for a mobile video rig.  I work in the film industry and it would be VERY beneficial to run my video cart from battery power, as opposed to always having to plug into AC mains.  I would love to use off-the-shelf components to distribute DC power for my various video devices, so in case of failure I'm minimizing my need to break out tools and a soldering iron, and can just replace parts.  I would utilize 12-14v batteries common to film sets for this.

I use 2 large production OLED monitors than can be powered via AC or DC, and DC can range from 12-24v.  However the consumption of the monitors is about 50w each, which is just over 4 amps per monitor at 12v, which exceeds the per-port capacity ratings for the off-the-shelf DC power distribution components I'm considering - using 4-pin XLR connectors.

My idea is to put a small voltage step-up regulator on the back of each monitor to boost the nominal 12-14vdc to roughly 24v, which would bring the amperage draw for each monitor down to just over 2A for each monitor, if I understand correctly.  My question is, am I correct in my assumption here that this would NOT overload the XLR circuits for the monitors in the power distribution equipment by adding these regulators?  I know I'll have some energy loss due to the conversion, and how would this potentially effect other 12v equipment on on the same power network, all pulling from a single 30Ah LifePo battery?  Would it be better to put the dedicated circuits for these step-up converters directly from the battery on their own lines separate from the rest of the distro?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you put a 12V -> 24V converter between your power distribution setup and the monitor, the 50W monitor will only draw 2 Amp from the converter, but the converter will draw 4 Amp from your 12 V source - the inverter needs to draw 50 watts (actually, a little more to allow for inefficiency) from the power source to be able to feed 50 watts to the monitor.

I suggest a separate battery for each monitor - that may give 5 hours run time (perhaps less, depending on how far you can safely discharge the battery) for each monitor.

Comment: @Chris Ratledge: the principle at play here is conservation of energy (which works out to conservation of power, if you're using an energy conversion device that doesn't store energy).  50W in at 12V is going to draw 4 1/6 amps.  Bumping the voltage up will reduce the current you need to get 50W on the high voltage side, but you'll still need to supply that power on the 12V side.

Comment: ah, so if the battery I'm looking to use is a 15A max draw, then regardless of sending the monitors 12v or 24v, the Amp draw for 2 of them is going to be roughly 8.25 amps - more than half the battery.  It sounds like I may have to run the monitors off of one battery and the rest of my rig off of another battery, which complicates things but doesn't sound avoidable with the components I plan to use.  Is this a correct assumption based on your info?

Comment: A bettery rated at 30 Ah can theoretically deliver 3 Amps for 10 hours before becoming fully discharged - but you probably shouldn't  use more than half the Ah rating to avoid damaging the battery, so one 30 Ah battery can only supply one 4 Amp monitor for 3 - 4 hours.  You probably need one battery for each monitor, and another one (or two?) for your other equipment for 4 hours of operation.